# Group theory - buildings/complexes, retractions Suzuki

Tags: gr.group-theory, buildings

I’m reading this book called group theory I by Michio Suzuki and part of a proof I just cannot figure out. It’s on page 322 proposition 3.18. I will include it here:

> **(3.18)** Let $\Delta$ be a building, and let $\Sigma$ be an apartment of $\Delta$. Assume that the two chambers $C$ and $C'$ of $\Sigma$ are adjacent. Then, there are foldings $\varphi$ and $\varphi'$ of $\Sigma$ such that
>
> $$\varphi(C')=C\quad\text{and}\quad \varphi'(C)=C'.$$
>
> We have $\Sigma=\varphi(\Sigma)\cup\varphi'(\Sigma)$. Furthermore, $\varphi(\Sigma)$ and $\varphi'(\Sigma)$ have no chamber in common. The mapping $\sigma$ defined by
>
> $$\sigma(a)=
> \begin{cases}
> \varphi'(A) & \text{if }A\in\varphi(\Sigma)\\
> \varphi(A) & \text{if }A\in\varphi'(\Sigma)
> \end{cases}$$
>
> is an automorphism of order $2$ of $\Sigma$.
>
> *Proof:* Let $B$ be a common wall of $C$ and $C'$. By Axiom (B1) of a building, there is a third chamber $C''$ which contains $B$. By Axiom (B3) there is an apartment of $\Sigma'$ which contains $C$ and $C''$. Let $\varphi$ be the restriction of the product
>
> $${\rm retr}(\Sigma', C){\rm retr}(\Sigma, C')$$
>
> on the apartment $\Sigma$. Clearly, $\varphi(\Sigma)\subset \Sigma$ and $\varphi(C)=C$. But, we have $\varphi(C')\neq C'$. This may be proved as follows. [. . .]

I just can’t see why we have $\phi (\Sigma ) \subset \Sigma $. It makes sense that $\text{retr}(\Sigma , C’)(\Sigma ) = \Sigma $ as $\text{retr}(\Sigma , C’) $ fixed every element of $\Sigma $ but can’t then see why this containment is the case.

Anyone out here who understands this stuff/ this book?

Comment: I'm on a tight schedule so I can't sort out your question at the moment, but I wanted to point you to Brown's book "Buildings", which is a very gentle introduction to this sort of stuff (probably easier to read than Suzuki, though I've never opened Suzuki myself).

Comment: Thank you I will take a look. I’m introducing myself to this stuff which is quite different to things I have done before so makes for quite a difficult read to be honest

Comment: Having only skimmed the details, and not thought very hard, is it possible that the composition is just happening left to right? So the last step is to retract onto $\Sigma$ and then of course the image lands in $\Sigma$?

Comment: Actually, on page viii, Suzuki explicitly says that when speaking of products $fg$ of maps he means the composition left to right. Thus, Matt Zaremsky guess is correct.

Comment: Haha you’re absolutely right. It does say this. When you’re so used to it reading right to left it’s hard to get used to it being the other way. Thanks

Comment: BTW,  the first version of Brown’s buildings book is the gentle introduction.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: That’s a good point.  I own the later massively larger book that Brown wrote with Abramenko as well, and it’s so different from the original that I basically think of them as two different books.